# replace all content with checkboxes and revert on cancel in jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, revert

```
<div>
    <div class="first">First Name</div>
    <div class="last">Last Name</div>


    <div class="edit">edit</div>
</div>
```

When pressing edit, I would like the content inside .first and .last to be replaced with a textbox with the content of the div inside the textbox.  Essentially, making the content noticeably editable.

I was able to achieve that with replaceWith.

However, if they click "edit" and then want to cancel, I need the textbox's to disappear and the original content show back up.  I realized replaceWith would ruin the existing structure.

I had the idea of using clone, but I'm not sure if that is efficient.

What would be the best way to approach this with jQuery?

I found this [how to make jquery-ui.dialog revert a form on cancel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032410/how-to-make-jquery-ui-dialog-revert-a-form-on-cancel) which seemed to do something similar to what I needed but I wasn't able to find anything in it that would help do what I wish.

Thanks so much, and I look forward to a reply!

Jacob

Comment: How about using .hide() and .show() to switch the textboxes and original content instead? I don't think that this is going to be significantly faster than using clone(), but it will probably be shorter and easier to understand.

Comment: How about using the `contenteditable` attribute on the DIV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/manishie/pZHMN/

It could use some refactoring, but it does what you want.  Basically you save the original value as a data attribute of the enclosing div.  If a user saves, you save the new value.  If a user cancels, you grab the old value from the data attribute and put that back in.

HTML:

```
<form id="theform">
    <div>
        <div class="first editable">First Name</div>
        <div class="last editable">Last Name</div>


        <div class="edit">edit</div>
        <div class="save" style="display:none;">save</div>
        <div class="cancel" style="display:none;">cancel</div>
    </div>
</form>​
```

Javascript:

```
$('.edit').click(function() {
    $('.edit').hide();
    $('.save,.cancel').show();

    $('.editable').each(function(index, el) {
        $(el).attr('data-orig', $(el).html());           
        $(el).html('<input type="text" value="' + $(el).attr('data-orig') + '">');
    });
});    

$('.save').click(function() {
    $('.edit').show();
    $('.save,.cancel').hide();

      $('.editable').each(function(index, el) {
        $(el).attr('data-orig', '');   
        $(el).html($(el).find('input').val());
    });            
});

$('.cancel').click(function() {
    $('.edit').show();
    $('.save,.cancel').hide();

      $('.editable').each(function(index, el) {
        $(el).html($(el).attr('data-orig'));
        $(el).attr('data-orig', '');   
    });            
});​
```

Comment: Interesting!  I had no idea you could save values as an attribute with data-orig.  Thank you :)

Jobby seemed to have the similar idea. Thanks!

Comment: actually i just came up with the name data-orig.  the html5 spec allows for attribute names prepended with 'data-', which you can use for just about anything you want.  http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Comment: well i didn't even know about the data- prefix so its so cool.  thank you